# MySQL How get record who have exactly label 1 and label 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table:

```
ID      Name    label
1       Jan     1
2       Jan     2
3       Adam    2
4       Adam    10
5       Kasia   1
```

I would like get records only with label 1 and label 2

For example:

```
1       Jan
```

I have many labels, so subselect in subselect in subselect... is it bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in various ways.  My preferred method is `group by` and `having`:

```
select min(id), name
from table
group by name
having sum(case when label = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when label = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 ;
```

For each name, this counts the number of times that "1" appears and that "2" appears.  The `> 0` ensure that each appears at least once.

Answer (score 1):

One other approach is to use a `intersect` operator.

```
 select id, name
 from tablename where label = 1 
 intersect
 select id, name
 from tablename where label = 2
```

Comment: This is good way, but I forgotten clarified, that I use MySQL. Intersect is not supported.